# Get some embeded elements

Tags: jquery, html

In html below, how can I just select/get the date by a given class?

```
<div class="blockCarouselAbsoluteSalons blockCarouselAbsolute" id="myCarousel">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li class="carousel-elem needed">
            <div class="date" style="background-color:red;">
                <p>1955</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blockGoToElem">
                <a href="ajax/salons_history_text.php?id=12" class="ajaxHistory">
                    <img src="img/aboutus/carousel-img3.png" class="" />
                </a>
                <div class="captionText">
                    <img src="img/px.gif" alt=""/>
                    <span>L’Oréal invents haircolour as we know it today</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-elem notneeded">
            <div class="date" style="background-color:#5297B3;">
                <p>1959</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blockGoToElem">
                <a href="ajax/salons_history_video.php" class="ajaxHistory"><img src="img/aboutus/carousel-img3.png" class="" /></a>
                <div class="captionText">
                    <img src="img/px.gif" alt=""/>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-elem notneeded">
            <div class="date" style="background-color:#3C9F9C;">
                <p>1967</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blockGoToElem ">
                <a href="ajax/salons_history_text.php?id=12" class="ajaxHistory"><img src="img/aboutus/carousel-img3.png" class="" /></a>
                <div class="captionText">
                    <img src="img/px.gif" alt=""/>
                    <span>L’Oréal ipsum</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-elem needed">
            <div class="date" style="background-color:#3C9F4F;">
                <p>1974</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blockGoToElem">
                <a href="ajax/salons_history_text.php?id=12" class="ajaxHistory"><img src="img/aboutus/carousel-img3.png" class="" /></a>
                <div class="captionText">
                    <img src="img/px.gif" alt=""/>
                    <span>L’Oréal invents haircolour as we know it today, fluctuat nec mergitur</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-elem needed">
            <div class="date" style="background-color:purple;">
                <p>1992</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blockGoToElem">
                <a href="ajax/salons_history_text.php?id=12" class="ajaxHistory"><img src="img/aboutus/carousel-img3.png" class="" /></a>
                <div class="captionText">
                    <img src="img/px.gif" alt=""/>
                    <span>L’Oréal ipsum</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#myCarousel .needed').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).find('.date p').text();    
    // do stuff with date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector `#myCarousel .needed .date p`.

Comment: I dont neet all date but just where we have ( needed class li class: <li class="carousel-elem needed">

Comment: Just want to select all date not in <li> tag with class notneeded

Answer (score 0):

Use this JQuery script:

```
$('.needed .date').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).find('p').text();
    alert(date);
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/HVQff/9/

Comment: Just from looking at your answer, the resulting `i` is equal to the length of the jQuery object: `var i = $('.date').length;`. What I mean is, you don't need to count inside the each() loop.

Comment: @SimeVidas - Thanks for that advice I'll update the above - coming from Java programming

Comment: Inside your each() callback, the `this` value references the current `.date` element, so - to get the date value - you just have to write this: `var date = $(this).find('p').text();`

Comment: @SimeVidas - That's pretty damn cool, I have got to get more into JQ